# Wcf service in virtual directory on shared hosting

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, wcf, next.js

I am working on a next js project and I need to call a wcf service. I deploy the service on a subdomain. Next js is giving error that as the site is on secure server the service should also be on secure server so I made a virtual directory and deploy my service on that. The service is running on https://example.com/Service1.svc but if I call some method like https://example.com/Service1.svc/getusers it is giving 404 resource not found error. How can I configure the service to run on a virtual directory. Also is there a way next js can call the service from a non secure domain. Thanks.

Comment: Can https://example.com/Service1.svc be accessed normally? I think this may be caused by you accessing the wrong URL. If you are using webhttpbinding, you can enable the help document to view the correct URL path.

Comment: example.com/service1.svc is showing that service is running but it is not accessing any methods in the service. Please explain how to get the correct path of the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on the net. It was the webconfig settings. My setting was

```
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding ....>
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

I changed it to

```
<bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding ....>
            <security mode="Transport"/>
          </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
```

and the service started working. My service was on https and now I can access the methods in the service.